# My remove() isn't removing from a linked list

Tags: pointers, binary-search-tree, delete-operator

This is driving me nuts. I've made a binary search tree class that functions like a set, automatically balancing numbers etc, with the nodes each having three values, the `left` and `right` pointers and `T data`. I've gotten everything to work except the remove method, and for some reason it doesn't actually remove...no segfault or anything. There is a destructor built into the class that works, I tested it. What am I doing wrong? This is the remove method, and the methods that it uses.

```
template < class T >
void binSTree< T >::remove( Node < T >*& passedNode, const T& targetValue )
{
    if( passedNode->data == targetValue ) //if the passed node is the target value
    {
        if ( passedNode->left == NULL && passedNode->right == NULL ) //if it has no children at all
        {
            Node < T >* parentNode = parent( passedNode);
            if( parentNode->left == passedNode )
                parentNode->left = NULL;
            else
                parentNode->right = NULL;

            delete passedNode; //simply delete it, it won't be missed
            return;
        }
        else if ( passedNode->left == NULL && passedNode->right != NULL ) //otherwise if it has left children
        {
            popout( passedNode, passedNode->left ); //connect previous node with left and remove current
            return;
        }
        else if ( passedNode->left != NULL && passedNode->right == NULL ) //otherwise if it has right children
        {
            popout( passedNode, passedNode->right ); //connect previous node with right and remove current
            return;
        }
        else if ( passedNode->left != NULL && passedNode->right != NULL ) //otherwise if it has both children
        {
            //now we have to find the closest lower value, i.e. the rightmost value to the left

            Node < T >* currentNode = pred( passedNode ); //start with the left child

            passedNode->data = currentNode->data; //set the value of our original node to the current one we are on

            popout( currentNode, currentNode->right ); //bypass and delete the current node
        }
    }
}

template < class T >
Node < T >* binSTree< T >::pred( Node < T >* passedNode)
{
    if( passedNode->left == NULL ) //if it has no left childen,
        return parent( passedNode ); //then the next lowest number is its parent
    else
    {
        Node < T >* currentNode = passedNode->left; //make an iterator and move left

        while( currentNode->right != NULL )
            currentNode = currentNode->right; //then move right until leaf

        return currentNode;
    }
}

template < class T >
Node < T >* binSTree< T >::parent( Node < T >* passedNode)
{
    Node < T >* currentNode = passedNode;

    while( currentNode->left != NULL && currentNode->right != NULL ) //while we are not yet at a leaf
    {
        if( currentNode->left == passedNode || currentNode->right == passedNode ) //if either child is it
            return currentNode; //return the current value

        else if( passedNode->data < currentNode->data ) //otherwise if the passedNode is less than where we are
            currentNode = currentNode->left; //turn left
        else //if the passedNode is greater than where we are
            currentNode = currentNode->right;
    }

    cerr << "No parent detected for node with value " << passedNode->data << endl;
    //print an error hear if it ended the loop
}
template < class T >
void binSTree< T >::popout( Node < T >*& targetNode, Node < T >*& childNode )
{
    Node < T >* parentNode = parent( targetNode ); //set the parent
    if( parentNode->left == targetNode ) //if the left matches our target node
        parentNode->left = childNode; //replace it with the childNode

    else if( parentNode->right == targetNode ) //if the right matches our target node
        parentNode->right = childNode; //replace it with the child node

    else //this is only done if for some reason the target is neither child
        cerr << "An error occurred, parent/target mismatch for parent with value "
             << parentNode->data << " and target with value " << targetNode->data << endl;

    delete targetNode; //now that it has been bypassed, delete the target
}
```

Comment: Aren't the first two conditions for "else if" switched?

Comment: You are definitely right...but is there anything else? Unfortunately I can't test it, the server with the rest of my program seems to be down.

Comment: I could bang my head against it, but it would be a struggle for me to do so... :-). But I don't feel guilty because there are people on SO who can figure this out before their morning coffee